# What is the meaning of 심심상케?

Tags: meaning

In my studies, I came across the following sentence (transcribed by myself, so I may have introduced errors):

> 이 표현은 일상 대화뿐만 아니라 방송 프로그램에서도 심심상케 들을 수 있는데요.

What is the meaning of 심심상케 here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 심심찮게, from [심심찮다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=24149200), which means "rather often".

(The word is literally a contraction of 심심하지 않다 "not boring", but acquired a different meaning.)

Comment: 심심하지 아니하게 -> 심심치 아니하게 | 심심하지 않게 -> 심심치 않게 -> 심심찮게